# How to insert '' (2 apostrophes) into sql

Tags: c#, sql, npgsql

I need to insert '' (2 apostrophes) into a column. 
Just the apostrophes without any text. 
But I end up inserting \'\' (apostrophes with backslashes)

```
        NpgsqlCommand Cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT into Table(Col) VALUES(@value), conn);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", "''");
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Result:   \'\'   Appears in my table.

If I use less or more apostrophes it inserts fine but I need exactly 2 and then for some reason backslashes appear.

Comment: “Result: \'\' Appears in my table” where? In the debugger? In SQL Management console? As the result of a query you're not showing us?

Comment: I just use PgAdmin to visual check the contents of the table.

Comment: Can you fix your code to compile? I don't see how that `new` can work in c#...

Comment: You're also missing a closing parenthesis in your INSERT statement

Comment: I strongly suspect this is just PgAdmin escaping things when it displays the value. Try selecting the length of the value, and I suspect you'll see it's 2, not 4.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a lot of confusion in the results above.

Npgsql does not perform any escaping in parameters, because they are sent out of band and are not treated in SQL. If your parameter value contains a C# string with two apostrophes, that is what will get inserted into the database.

After running your code above and using psql, I get the following:

```cs
var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT into foo (name) VALUES (@value)", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", "''");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

```
npgsql_tests=# select * from foo;
 name 
------
 ''
(1 row)
```

Maybe pgadmin shows values with backslashes - I don't know - but that would be a display issue.

Finally, if you really want to insert a constant value (as opposed to a user-provided one), there's no reason to use parameters. Just embed your value in SQL:

```sql
INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES ('''''');
```

There are six apostrophes in there: 2 as the string delimiters, and two more escaped apostrophes (in SQL, '' is the escaped form of a single literal apostrophe).

However, if you're reading input from the user, definitely use a parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Try to double up each apostrophe.

> Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("value", "''''");

Comment: Then it inserts all 4 of them normally.

Answer (score -1):

Adding an empty text box and using it's text value somehow let's me insert the double apostrophes.

So the answer would be

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand (INSERT into Table (Col) VALUES (@value);
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", textBox1.text);
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Where texBox1 is just an empty text box.

Probably not the best way of doing this but it works for now.

Comment: An empty text box's text value will just be an empty string. Are you trying to insert literally `''` into a column or the empty string in a column? Cause if you want an empty string, just use `""` or `String.Empty`.

Comment: This is inserting an empty string. I very strongly suspect the problem is in how you're interpreting what you're seeing, not in the data itself.